# Dynamic Combobox in Extjs6.5 not working

Tags: extjs

I try to create a combobox(with autoCompleted) and a remote store.When a user types some letters in the combobox,it goes to the server to take a new Datastore.
And I get nothing in my combobox.What's wrong with my code?How can I do for this?

Here's my combobox:

```
Ext.define('HDDTest.view.mod.searchDetails', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    controller: 'home',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            width: 450,
            id: 'createRelatedConceptComboBox',
            name: 'createRelatedConceptComboBox',
            fieldLabel: 'Test',
            //hideTrigger:true,
            valueField: 'text',
            emptyText: 'Select Concept',
            typeAhead: true,
            typeAheadDelay: 350,
            minChars: 1,
            listeners: {
                change: 'onRelatedConceptComboBoxClicked'
            },
            store: {
                type: 'GetRelatedConceptStore'
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Here's my controller:

```
Ext.define('HDDTest.controller.main.HomeController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.home',

    onRelatedConceptComboBoxClicked: function (constructors, text) {
        var getRelatedConceptStore = Ext.create('HDDTest.store.GetRelatedConceptStore');
        getRelatedConceptStore.load({
            params: {
                sValue: 'text'
            },
            callback: function (records, success) {
            },
            scope: this
        });
    }
});
```

Here's my store:

```
Ext.define('HDDTest.store.GetRelatedConceptStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    field: ['value', 'text'],
    alias: 'store.GetRelatedConceptStore',
    storeId: 'GetRelatedConceptStore',
    autoSync: true,
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: "http://127.0.0.1/api/TSGH/GetAllSearchResults",
        method: 'GET',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: '',
            transform: function (records) {
                var data = new Array();
                for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                    data[i] = new Array();
                    data[i][0] = records[i].NCID;
                    data[i][1] = records[i].DEFAULT_NAME + '(' + records[i].NCID + ')';
                }
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

When I type some letters in my combobox I get nothing and without any error messages in my console window. How can I do for this?
Thanks in advance, Ben

Comment: Give some fiddle it will help to understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some error in the processing of **transform()** method or the Model field name for the **displayField** property.

[Here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27i7) is the working code with **transform()** method commented out.